# What is the bug with this code

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#2962ff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="SWAMI VIVEKANAND The Great Philosopher"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Famous Personalities Born on Jan 12"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="ZAYN MALIK The Popstar"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="PRIYANKA GANDHI The Politician"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
```

I am new to android and I am not able to figure out the bug in this piece of code
I have tried this on android studio but the text views do not appear only the text view saying Famous personalities born on Jan 12 appears on the top
nothing else
Please help
[This is what shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdgof.png)

Comment: remove `enter code here`, also change other textview height to wrap_content

Comment: you just started wrong tag `<linearLayout`  its `<LinearLayout`, L must be capital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using linear layout in vertical orientation then use layout_height=0 otherwise if you are using linear layout in horizontal orientation then use layout_width=0 for all TextViews.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#2962ff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="SWAMI VIVEKANAND The Great Philosopher"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Famous Personalities Born on Jan 12"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="ZAYN MALIK The Popstar"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="PRIYANKA GANDHI The Politician"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `orientation="horizontal"` which means al child views are laid out horizontally next to each other. Also, your textviews have `layout_width="match_parent"` which means they take up the entire width.

This results in you only seeing 1 textview. The others are there as well, but you cannot see them since they are off-screen.

The solution should be to change the orientation to vertical.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to change  `<linearlayout` to `<Linearlayout`. After then if you want to textview alignment `vertically` , you just have to set orientation `android:orientation="vertical"` ,

**or**

if you want to textview alignment `horizontally`, you have to change then change bit  of code `android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"` and orientation of linearlayout `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Answer (score -1):

Change orientation to `Vertical`:[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#2962ff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="SWAMI VIVEKANAND The Great Philosopher"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Famous Personalities Born on Jan 12"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="ZAYN MALIK The Popstar"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="PRIYANKA GANDHI The Politician"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
</LinearLayout>
```